# How to customize registration provided by Flask-security?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

What am i supposed to do, if need to set up Role of user to, for example `FooUser`? Where i need to do this? In my own `/create_account` view or in context processor?

```
@app.route('/create_account')
def create_account():
    user_datastore.find_or_create_role('FooUser')
    user_datastore.add_role_to_user(user,role)
    return render_template('register_user.html')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may customize views following these instructions:
http://flask-security.readthedocs.org/en/latest/customizing.html

And you may hook into the user registration process using signals:
http://flask-security.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#signals

Comment: I don't understand a process of hooking. And now i supposed to use first variant. Deadline is coming.

Comment: But why, when i add extra fields, they are rendered only after ```register``` button?

Answer (score 2):

IMPORTANT! Second way is pretty simple.

`@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def user_registered_sighandler(sender, **extra):
    sender.logger.debug("logger-user_registered_sighandler:", extra)
    user  = extra.get('user')
    role = user_datastore.find_or_create_role('farmer')
    user_datastore.add_role_to_user(user,role)
    db.session.commit()
    print "print-user_registered_sighandler:", extra`

Answer (score 1):

To add a role to a user you have to use flask-security's API:

```
flask_security.datastore.UserDatastore.add_role_to_user(user, role)
```

Defninitely you will do this inside your own **create_account** or similar code. **ContextProcessors** are used to prepare data before rendering templates. It means that you create or get **User** and **Role** objects then call the above API to assign the role to the user. Be more specific if you need further help.