# Flask-security - how to get form data in user_registered signal?

Tags: python, flask, flask-security

I started [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25376647/how-to-customize-registration-provided-by-flask-security), and now I have this code:

```
@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def user_registered_sighandler(sender, **extra):
    sender.logger.debug("logger-user_registered_sighandler:", extra)
    user  = extra.get('user')
    print dir(sender)
    role = user_datastore.find_or_create_role('farmer')
    user_datastore.add_role_to_user(user,role)
    db.session.commit()
    print "print-user_registered_sighandler:", extra
```

Now I'm interested in getting data from the register form. I need to do this because inside the form are some useful fields for another database model. How can I access the form data in this context processor? Maybe I should change the [`register_user`](https://github.com/mattupstate/flask-security/blob/develop/flask_security/registerable.py#L26) method and add some extra kwargs?

Answer (score -1):

You can take advantage of `flask.g` object. Put whatever you want on it and use it in your signal handler.

from flask [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.g):

flask.g

```
Just store on this whatever you want. For example a database connection or the user that is currently logged in.

user = getattr(flask.g, 'user', None)
user = flask.g.get('user', None)
```