# How to get user registered signal in Flask-User

Tags: python, flask

With Flask-User, I would like to get user registered signal like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25407727/flask-security-how-to-get-form-data-in-user-registered-signal).

However the error "NameError: name 'app' is not defined" has occured.
I do not know where I have to place "@user_registered" hook.

How can do that?

mdsys__init__.py

```py
import os

from flask import (Flask, render_template, url_for)
from mdsys.db import init_db, db
from flask_mail import Mail
from flask_user import UserManager, SQLAlchemyAdapter
from mdsys.model.auth import User, Role

def create_app(test_config=None):
    # create and configure the app
    app = Flask(__name__, instance_relative_config=True)

    app.config.from_mapping(
        SECRET_KEY='dev',
        SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI='postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}/{dbname}'.format(**{
            'user': 'hoge',
            'password': 'pass',
            'host': 'localhost',
            'dbname': 'hogehoge',
        }),
        SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS=False,

        # Flask-Mail settings
        MAIL_USERNAME = 'hoge@example.com',
        MAIL_PASSWORD = 'pass',
        MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER = '"MdSys" <no-reply@example.com>',
        MAIL_SERVER = 'smtp.gmail.com',
        MAIL_PORT = 465,
        MAIL_USE_SSL = True,

        # Flask-User settings
        USER_ENABLE_USERNAME = False,    # Register and Login with username
        USER_ENABLE_CHANGE_USERNAME=False,
        USER_APP_NAME = "MdSys",    # Used by email templates
        USER_CHANGE_PASSWORD_TEMPLATE      = 'auth/change_password.html',
        USER_CHANGE_USERNAME_TEMPLATE      = 'auth/change_username.html',
        USER_FORGOT_PASSWORD_TEMPLATE      = 'auth/forgot_password.html',
        USER_INVITE_TEMPLATE               = 'auth/invite.html',
        USER_INVITE_ACCEPT_TEMPLATE        = 'auth/register.html',
        USER_LOGIN_TEMPLATE                = 'auth/login.html',
        USER_MANAGE_EMAILS_TEMPLATE        = 'auth/manage_emails.html',
        USER_REGISTER_TEMPLATE             = 'auth/register.html',
        USER_RESEND_CONFIRM_EMAIL_TEMPLATE = 'auth/resend_confirm_email.html',
        USER_RESET_PASSWORD_TEMPLATE       = 'auth/reset_password.html',
        USER_CHANGE_PASSWORD_URL      = '/auth/change-password',
        USER_CHANGE_USERNAME_URL      = '/auth/change-username',
        USER_CONFIRM_EMAIL_URL        = '/auth/confirm-email/<token>',
        USER_EMAIL_ACTION_URL         = '/auth/email/<id>/<action>',
        USER_FORGOT_PASSWORD_URL      = '/auth/forgot-password',
        USER_INVITE_URL               = '/auth/invite',
        USER_LOGIN_URL                = '/auth/login',
        USER_LOGOUT_URL               = '/auth/logout',
        USER_MANAGE_EMAILS_URL        = '/auth/manage-emails',
        USER_REGISTER_URL             = '/auth/register',
        USER_RESEND_CONFIRM_EMAIL_URL = '/auth/resend-confirm-email',
        USER_RESET_PASSWORD_URL       = '/auth/reset-password/<token>',
        USER_AFTER_LOGOUT_ENDPOINT    = 'auth.login',
        USER_UNCONFIRMED_EMAIL_ENDPOINT = 'auth.login',
        USER_UNAUTHENTICATED_ENDPOINT = 'auth.login',
        USER_ENABLE_RETYPE_PASSWORD   = False,
    )

    with app.app_context():
        init_db(app)

        # Setup Flask-User
        db_adapter = SQLAlchemyAdapter(db, User)    # Register the User model
        user_manager = UserManager(db_adapter, app) # Init Flask-User and bind to app

        if not Role.query.filter(Role.name=='admin').first():
            role1 = Role(name='admin')
            db.session.add(role1)
            db.session.commit()

    mail = Mail(app)

    if test_config is None:
        # load the instance config, if it exists, when not testing
        app.config.from_pyfile('config.py', silent=True)
    else:
        # load the test config if passed in
        app.config.from_mapping(test_config)

    # ensure the instance folder exists
    try:
        os.makedirs(app.instance_path)
    except OSError:
        pass


    from . import auth
    app.register_blueprint(auth.bp)

    return app
```

mdsys\db.py

```py
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate

db = SQLAlchemy()   # Initialize Flask-SQLAlchemy

def init_db(app):
    db.init_app(app)
    Migrate(app, db)
```

mdsys\model\auth.py

```py
from flask_user import UserMixin, user_registered
from datetime import datetime
from mdsys.db import db

class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(255), nullable=False, default='')
    confirmed_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    expire_at = db.Column(db.DateTime())
    is_enabled = db.Column(db.Boolean(), nullable=False, default=False)
    created_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now)
    updated_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, nullable=False, default=datetime.now, onupdate=datetime.now)
    # Relationships
    roles = db.relationship('Role', secondary='user_roles',
            backref=db.backref('users', lazy='dynamic'))

    def is_active(self):
        return self.is_enabled

class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(50), unique=True)

class UserRoles(db.Model):
    __table_args__ = {'extend_existing': True}
    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('users.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
    role_id = db.Column(db.Integer(), db.ForeignKey('roles.id', ondelete='CASCADE'))
```

mdsys\auth.py

```py
import functools

from flask import (
    Blueprint, flash, g, redirect, render_template, request, session, url_for
)

from werkzeug.security import check_password_hash, generate_password_hash

from mdsys.db import db
from mdsys.model.auth import User, Role
from flask_user import user_registered

bp = Blueprint('auth', __name__, url_prefix='/auth')


@bp.route('/register', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def register():
    return render_template('auth/register.html')

@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def _after_user_registered_hook(sender, user, **extra):
    user.roles.append(Role(name='free'))
```

I do not know how to separate the code to multiple files like models/hogehoge.py, db.py, **init**.py.
Most of tutorials I can find define all in one file.

Answer (score 1):

According to the newest [flask-user docs](https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html) you can use

```
from flask_user.signals import user_registered

@user_registered.connect_via(app)
def _after_registration_hook(sender, user, **extra):
    print('user is registered', sender, user)
```

and place it after the `app.config`